# FPS counter in Steam Big Picture mode

Tags: steam

Is there a way to get the FPS counter to appear in Steam when using the Big Picture mode? I do not usually use the Big Picture mode, but occasionally I do due to having a steam controller. I know how to do it in the typical client, but cannot figure out how to do it in the Big Picture mode if there is even a way yet. It seems minimal but I really like to see how my system is doing while playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not implemented in Big Picture mode. I'd suggest just downloading the trial of FRAPS and using their FPS counter until Valve implements it.